# Spring Boot Dev Tools Turning them off for production?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I was reading around a lot about spring dev tools and I have tried them on and they seem pretty cool.  However,  I don't understand how they get enabled / disabled.  For instance just adding the dependency, everything magically works, but what if I wanted to deploy my code to production?  Are the dev tools still running and I need to disable them with a profile or something?

Comment: Just by adding a dependency, they will be on the classpath when you run the app so that Spring Boot will find them and activate them. For production, make sure you don't include the devtools jar file(s) in the classpath; or in your build, use for example Maven profiles and make sure the devtools are not included as a dependency for the production build.

Comment: Ok so I should add the dependency to a developer profile or something like that enable it or disable it.  Is there an alternative option of using an environment variable to configure it or does it have to be a profile?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No, it's turned off automatically.

From the [Spring Boot reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools):

> Developer tools are automatically disabled when running a fully
>   packaged application. If your application is launched using java -jar
>   or if it’s started using a special classloader, then it is considered
>   a “production application”. Flagging the dependency as optional is a
>   best practice that prevents devtools from being transitively applied
>   to other modules using your project. Gradle does not support optional
>   dependencies out-of-the-box so you may want to have a look to the
>   propdeps-plugin in the meantime.

and

> If you want to ensure that devtools is never included in a production
>   build, you can use the excludeDevtools build property to completely
>   remove the JAR. The property is supported with both the Maven and
>   Gradle plugins.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much Brian I was having a hard time finding this.  Is there a documentation link for these so I can read more?

Comment: Yes, it's already available as a link in my answer: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools
The reference guide is well, the reference when it comes to Boot features :-)

Comment: Here's another stackoverflow answer with some more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759587/intellij-spring-dev-tools-remote-docker-error-unexpected-404-response-uploadi/47425443#47425443

Answer (score 24):

It is excluded automatically for Spring Boot applications that use the JAR packaging.  However, for WAR packaged Spring Boot projects, it is not.  For Maven Spring Boot projects you must mark the dependency as `provided` and also set `excludeDevTools=true` in your `pom.xml`.

Change devtools to "provided"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Exclude devtools from maven spring build plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

More information here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7556

Comment: The `excludeDevtools` setting is `true` [by default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#excludeDevtools).

Comment: You are correct, but when packaging a WAR it is included unless specifically excluded regardless of the default value.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7556

Answer (score 1):

spring-boot-devtools is only for easing development effort. While packaging the application this dependency is not included. Cannot  be used to create a shippable product.

Comment: any reference (official documentation link) about that?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to use maven profiles and exclude it altogether in production environment.

Comment: The question is about turning off in production and as it is a library to assist development, i would prefer to exclude it altogether from final artefact using maven profile..